# How can I add a checkbox to a Manipulate expression?

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction, version-7

I'm looking for a simple example about how to add a simple On-Off switch in a manipulate function.

More specifically, I defined a curve with two parameters.  One is a continuous parameter that is changed using the manipulate slider.  The other one is a discrete parameter that takes two values only : 0 or 1.  I need to put that parameter as a check box in the manipulate output, above the continuous slider.  The check box should have a small line of text, which changes if the box is in its 0 state or its 1 state.

This is certainly very basic, but I can't find any clear example anywhere.

How can I implement what I described?

Comment: it's not a checkbox but maybe works?  `Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, 10}], {a, 0, 1, 1}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just want to point out the Edmund's fancy version of `Manipulate` is unnecessarily complicated. The same effects can be gotten with much simpler code.

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[Sin[a + b x], {x, 0, 10}],
  Row[{
    Control[{{a, 0, ""}, {0, 1}}],
    "  ",
    Dynamic @ Switch[a, 0, "Zero", 1, "One"]}],
  {{b, 1, ""}, 1, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: demo]

`Manipulate` allows a great deal of customization of controls, so it is seldom really necessary to use the kind of lower-level dynamic code that Edmund invoked (although such certainly works).

Also note that to insert a control specification such as `{{a, 0, ""}, {0, 1}}` into a formatting construct such as `Row`, one need only wrap it with `Control`.

#### Update

In a comment below, the OP asks: How do you place the button to the left, and the slider to the right?

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[a + b x], {x, 0, 10}],
   Row[{
     Control[{{a, 0, ""}, {0, 1}}],
     "  ",
     Dynamic @ Switch[a, 0, "Zero", 1, "One"],
     Spacer[80],
     Control[{{b, 1, ""}, 1, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]}]]
```

[image: variant]

The space between the two controls can be adjusted by changing the argument given to `Spacer`. For demonstration purposes, I have chosen a value that moves the slider to the far right.

Comment: How do you place the button to the left, and the slider to the right ?

Comment: So there isn't a command to push the slider to the right ?  We need to adjust it by eye, is that right ?

Comment: @Cham. I know of no simple command that will make the controls in a `Row` behave as there were a spring spacer between them. pushing them to space out over the full width of the panel they located in.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot.  So I'll use a spacing by eye-hand.  It's all working great anyway.

Answer (score 5):

A simple way is to define your `Manipulate` variable parameters so that they are recognised as the control type you want.  Look in the first part of the **Details and Options** section of [`Manipulate` documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html).

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[a + b x], {x, 0, 10}], {{a, 0}, {0, 1}}, {b, 1, 5}]
```

[image]

You can get fancier by specifying the controls and layout directly.

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a + b x], {x, 0, 10}],
 Column@{
   Row[{Checkbox[Dynamic@a, {0, 1}], Spacer[5], 
     Dynamic@Switch[a, 0, "Zero", 1, "One"]}],
   Slider[Dynamic@b, {1, 5}, Appearance -> "Labeled"]}
 ]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  It's working.  I think this is it.  I'll wait a bit in case someone else find a simpler method, before checking this as "THE" answer.

Comment: Why the Spacer[5] command ?  Removing it doesn't change anything, apparently.

Comment: Duh !  I see the spacing now !